# Skype for Business Presence

Tags: sharepoint, skype, user-presence, skype-for-business

Is it possible to display the presence of a Skype for Business user on a SharePoint Website? I am trying to create a contact page where users can contact of these employees from the webpage and to do this the presence needs to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Skype for web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962133(v=office.16).aspx) to display presence of user on a web application (including SharePoint website). Keep in mind SDK is still in **public preview**. You can subscribe to user presence as follows:

```
  sub = person1.status.subscribe();
  person1.status.changed(onPresenceChanged);
  function onPresenceChanged(presence) {
      console.log("the contact is " + presence.availability);
  }
```

Refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962150(v=office.16).aspx) for documentation.
To get the self presence use `status` property of `MePerson` object. Refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962127(v=office.16).aspx) for more details.

You can download the samples of SDK can be from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962133(v=office.16).aspx)

Comment: And here is a step by step example: https://www.matthewproctor.com/skype-web-sdk-presence-dashboard-revisited

Comment: But this will require a separate Azure app and a separate user authentication?...